# Странная NumberFormatException

Tags: java, android, kotlin, proxy, httpurlconnection

Итак, пишу чекер для прокси, получаемых через [api](https://api.proxyscrape.com/?request=displayproxies&proxytype=http). Принцип простой - сначала парсится список и с помощью split("\n") разбивается на отдельные прокси. Далее я перебираю циклом каждый прокси, применяю и get запросом на определенный ресурс, получаю ip, с которого произведен запрос, который в последствии сравниваю с ip прокси. Если все верно, то прокси идет в список рабочих. Казалось, что никаких проблем в работе такой схемы быть не должно, тем более уже есть готовый вариант на python, но... Проблемы пришли откуда не ждали.

В цикле проверки прокси я сначала разбиваю полученную мною строку типа "1.10.188.78:45208" с помощью split(":"), а затем этот строковый массив использую для применения прокси к запросу:

```
val p: List<String> = proxyList[i].split(":")
val proxy = Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, InetSocketAddress(p[0], p[1].toInt()))
```

Но как раз на моменте перевода p[1] в Int я ловлю NFE. Причем в строчке нет никаких символов, кроме цифр. Я пробовал и Integer.parseInt(p[1]), а так же переводить в Int до применения прокси, однако ловлю NFE. Когда же я попробовал сделать так, все работало, однако прокси приходят с разными портами и была уже другая ошибка:

```
val proxy = Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, InetSocketAddress(p[0], "8000".toInt()))
```

При этом в proxy чекерах с гитхаба все работает примерно так же, как [здесь](https://github.com/VexioPL/ProxyChecker/blob/master/src/net/vexio/proxychecker/checker/ProxyChecker.java) например.

Пример моего NFE:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8080"
```

Comment: [Похожая проблема](https://javarush.ru/help/16673)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте удалить невидимые символы в строке

```
val p: List<String> = proxyList[i].split(":")
val proxy = Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, InetSocketAddress(p[0].trim(), p[1].trim().toInt()))
```

Comment: Спасибо, более короткое решение

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо [Вася Воронцов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/312975/%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2), решил проблему вот так:

```
val p: List<String> = proxyList[i].split(":")
                    var int: String = p[1]
                    int = int.replace("[^0-9]", "")
                    println(int)
                    val proxy = Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, InetSocketAddress(p[0], int.toInt()))
```

Однако теперь стало понятно, что чекер не работает как надо и его надо чинить